# Continuous build and deployment of Angular-cli using TeamCity and Octopus

Tags: teamcity, angular-cli, octopus-deploy

I have developed my Angular 2 application using angular-cli. Now I am planning to deploy the application through Team City and Octopus Deploy. At present all the projects in Team City are ASP.NET MVC so there is no reference to use.

After searching I found that [TeamCity.Node](https://github.com/jonnyzzz/TeamCity.Node) plugin is required on Team City to build this app. Are there any other approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Install Node.js and npm on each build agent.
2. Install Team City plugin that adds a support for npm (like TeamCity.Node that you've mentioned).
3. Put angular-cli files (and any other required npm packages) into your source control, thus eliminating the need for npm.

Comment: Thanks. And for deployment using Octopus, do I have to just refer to the 6 files that were generated using ng-build

Comment: Yes. You should configure your *.nuspec file to include `ng build` output and other resources needed for your app at runtime.

Comment: Thanks. I configured my nuspec file and refereed all the files. Will Octopus automatically identify this nuspec file and deploy them?

Comment: Octopus will identify your *nuspec* if it is named as *YouProjectName.nuspec*. Then it will build *YouProjectName.nupkg* package that will automatically be published to Team City NuGet feed. Then you reference it in Octopus project step and it will deploy it.

Comment: I think I almost got all the information. By any chance do you mean "TeamCity will identify your nuspec.." instead of "Octopus will identify your nuspec ".

Comment: I meant OctoPack but it can be used only if you have csproj file. If all you have is just folder with Angular 2 application, I guess you should use nuget.exe (or built-in Team City NuGet Pack step) to pack *.nupkg.

Comment: Yes. What I have is just 5 bundles and an index.html file that got generated using angular-cli ng build. So to deploy these files, i) Create a nuspec file and refer all the files ii) Use nuget.exe or NuGet pack to pack *.nupkg which will be published to Team City NuGet feed iv) Refer the NuGet feed in Octopus project.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am able to create the Nupkg using NuGet pack. And it is created at the ouput path that I have specified. How can I specify the Team City NuGet feed path ?

Comment: When I open the Octopus it is looking for <project name>.web file. But what I have is 5 bundles created from Angular-cli